What is the difference between earlier and sooner in these contexts?
Person A gets a promotion in March and person B gets a promotion in May. Did Person A get a promotion 1 month earlier or sooner than Person B?
Their train left three minutes sooner or earlier than mine.
Newspaper A published the article a day sooner or earlier than Newspaper B.
Please, stick to my question. I always get only indirectly related information and it's frustrating that every time I come here for help, I have to walk away with practically nothing.

What are your B and C languages? Or do you have two B's? For interpreting, I mean. You did say you wanted to be an interpreter, right?. We have asked you many times to post research but you don't seem to want to.

I haven't enrolled in a training program yet for personal reasons but I have plans to do so. I'd like to have an A language and two B's. The reason for that is that my A language is a ''small'' language and there aren't many English A's or Chinese A's who have it as their C language.

What kind of research is needed here? I have trawled every website I could for an answer but I ended up even more confused. Hence, my post here where I am asking you for help. Please just tell me.

"What kind of research is needed here? I have trawled every website I could for an answer but I ended up even more confused." What's needed, in this question and others like it, would be something like: "Here's what I found in one of these websites [preferably a dictionary, when we're talking about individual words]." [Summarizes or even pastes dictionary entry.] "But that doesn't solve the problem for me because [talk about what's confusing in the entry or how it doesn't settle the issue]." This isn't just a hoop to jump through; it eliminates...

... eliminates people saying things that contradict the reference source, or forces them to explain more thoroughly; and if the source was faulty, it can be dismissed, and if it was confusing, it can be explained. All these are better answers than starting from scratch.


John was promoted sooner than Jim.
John was promoted earlier than Jim.

Though  many speakers wouldn't distinguish between the two words in this manner, sooner implies that the two employees were competing for a promotion, or at least they are being compared to each other by the speaker;  one was promoted ahead of the other for some reason related to their attributes.  earlier on the other hand doesn't have that aspect and is just a temporal thing that  does not touch upon their merits relative to each other.

Are they interchangeable? What about the other sentences?

For many people they would be interchangeable.

In your comment below the other post that was deleted, you said something contradictiory. Are they interchangeable now or not? Will native speakers think I am a ret*rd if I use them interchangeably or are these words perfectly interchangeably and whether I choose one over the other won't affect how natural I sound?

I'd really appreciate an answer.

[Sighs] I would use earlier in all those contexts, but I wouldn't find  sooner glaringly wrong.

Also see Sooner/earlier-interchangeability.

See if you can run with this: "earlier" always means "chronologically prior" to a contextual time or a specified time whereas  "sooner" means "in less time".  If you can decide which idea it is you wish to express, you will be able to choose properly.

@TimR: The fact that sooner often means in less time, faster, quicker is reflected in I'd sooner die than marry you!, where sooner = rather could just about be replaced by more willingly = more quickly, unhesitatingly, but earlier simply wouldn't make sense there.

@FumbleFingers  Understand "always" there to refer to the non-fixed-phrase contexts OP is asking about.   But even in your context, it's a figurative use of "in less time".  It would take me less time to choose to die than it would take me  to  choose to marry you. I'd die with greater eagerness. or "I'd be quicker to die".

I suppose you could say I'd sooner die than... is a "fixed phrase". But you could hardly say that about "When would you sooner come? Earlier or later?" There are a vast range of contexts where only sooner in the sense of in less time (metaphorically or literally) can be used, but earlier (chronologically before) won't work at all.

@K945 Comments are not the place for answers and this question has been locked. I look forward to contributing an answer to a valid version of this question, but I'll say that they are interchangeable in some contexts and not others, and they have different meaning. Meanwhile "I'd sooner ___" is kind of irrelevant to this discussion; it's a different idiomatic usage.

@FumbleFingers  Yes, but those are not really questions about a particular chronological priority or a length-of-time but a PREFERENCE.   If you want to quibble about what to caller "sooner" where it means "prefer", I'd sooner not.

@TimR "'sooner' means 'in less time'" —I would nuance this. The critical distinction is that "sooner" means closer in time. "That train arrives early": it arrives before its scheduled time (regardless of our frame of reference). "That train arrives soon": it arrives at a time not far from our own frame of reference.

@Andy Bonner, Tim: I'm not really trying to teach either of you guys anything about how English works. All native speakers know how to use their own language perfectly well, imho. My comments were intended to give this OP something he might understand, in order to decide where to use sooner, where to user earlier, and most importantly, where it doesn't really matter (that last being a particularly large category that the OP seems reluctant to recognize the existence of, let alone its scope! :)

@AndyBonner  I'm trying to give OP a succinct rule of thumb that will permit a decision between the one or the other word. If you feel like you can offer a better practical guide, go for it. "Closer in time" to what?   Bear in mind that OP is asking about sooner and earlier and deciding between them. Not early and not soon.

If the train reaches the destination before its scheduled time, you can express that fact either way:  If you want to say it arrived chronologically prior to its scheduled time of arrival, say "earlier than expected".  If you want to say it got there quicker than expected,  in less time, say "sooner than expected".  It's not that one or the other is right; it's that they state the fact in different ways.

With that distinction, OP won't end up saying things like  "I was there sooner today" when the desired meaning is "only a few hours ago". It's a chrono scenario, not "less time" scenario.

The 2.30 train is scheduled to arrive earlier than the 2.40. If the 2.30 has been delayed, you could say that the 2.40 arrived sooner than the 2.30 did.

@KateBunting I know in many instances either word could be used. But OP seems concerned about using the wrong word, so instead of cluttering OP's mind with such things, I'm saying this: decide whether you wish to speak of something as as occuring chronologically prior or as occuring in less time; user earlier for the chronological notion and sooner for the in-less-time notion, and you won't be wrong.  Example:  If we take this shortcut, we will get there _______.  You can decide whether you want to cast your remark in terms of the clock or the length of time it will take to get there.

@TimR - Yes, I know, and I upvoted your earlier comment. This was just an example that occurred to me as a way to demonstrate the difference.

@KateBunting  But it's the sort of thing that will send OP into conniptions. Because what sooner means there, implicitly, is that the delayed train took more time to get there than the undelayed train, and so the undelayed train took (relatively) less time to get there even though it didn't go any faster than it usually does.  We get into issues of absolute time and relative time, implicit comparison, etc.

So it doesn't matter then whether I say ''The red train arrive three minutes earlier than the blue one'' or ''The red train arrived three minutes sooner than the blue one''?

As many people have told you, it  is usual to use 'earlier' when talking about timetabled events.
